# Working with nested-list (to unknown degree) (Racket)

Tags: list, scheme, racket, nested-lists

This is my first time posting, so let me know if I mess anything up :)

This is an assignment where I can't import or use "for functions". So I have a nested list, but I do not know the degree that it is nested, so it could be something like so:

```
'(#<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt>)
or
'((#<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt>)
(#<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt>)
(#<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt>)
(#<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt>))
or
'(((#<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt>)
(#<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt>)
(#<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt>)
(#<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt>))
((#<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt>)
(#<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt>)
(#<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt>)
(#<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt>))
((#<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt>)
(#<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt>)
(#<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt>)
(#<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt>))
((#<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt>)
(#<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt>)
(#<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt>)
(#<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt> #<procedure:curried:tt>)))
or
4 times bigger then that
```

*Note: though it does not have to be by factors of 4*

I then have to apply one argument to each of the functions, *without* changing there position in the list, so the above functions might turn out to be:

```
'(1 2 3 4)
and
'((1 2 3 4)
(1 2 3 4)
(2 3 4 5)
(9 8 2 1))
and
'(((1 2 3 4)
(1 2 3 4)
(2 3 4 5)
(9 8 2 1))
((1 2 3 4)
(1 2 3 4)
(2 3 4 5)
(9 8 2 1))
((1 2 3 4)
(1 2 3 4)
(2 3 4 5)
(9 8 2 1))
((1 2 3 4)
(1 2 3 4)
(2 3 4 5)
(9 8 2 1)))
and so on
```

I am really confused on how to solve this problem for the *unknown degree* part. It is pretty simple to solve with a known degree, you just have a series of functions looping through with car and cdr. I honestly have no idea how to start for the *unknown degree* part, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can examine each element and see if it's a pair or not. That will give you clues about how and when to recurse. (It's not very different from working with a list of an unknown length.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically like traversing an s-expression. You can model the data like an s-expression:

```
; NestedFuncs is one of
; - Func
; - [List-of Nested-Funcs]
```

Once that is done, it's easy to traverse it. One function to do deal with the data and the second do traverse the list.

```
#lang racket

(define (apply-nfs nfs arg)
  (if (list? nfs)
      (apply-nf-list nfs arg)
      (nfs arg)))

(define (apply-nf-list nf arg)
  (if (empty? nf)
      '()
      (cons (apply-nfs (car nf) arg)
            (apply-nf-list (cdr nf) arg))))
```

Here's an example and output:

```
(define nf-ex
  `((,add1 ,sub1 ,sub1 ,add1)
    (,sub1 (,add1 ,add1) ,add1 ,sub1)
    (,add1 ,add1)
    (,add1 ,add1 (,sub1 (,add1)) ,add1)))

(apply-nfs nf-ex 3)
; => '((4 2 2 4) (2 (4 4) 4 2) (4 4) (4 4 (2 (4)) 4))
```